# Group/sum a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I need a script that will group/sum a CSV file by columns 1 to 4, summing column 5. The group/sum needs to only be on lines where column 1 ='2'. Below examples of input and required output.

Input (Input CSV):

[image]

Required Output (Correct Output CSV):

[image]

I've tried using the below python script:
import csv

```
input_file = r'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\test.csv'
output_file = r'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Flat file tests\output4.csv'

# Dictionary to store rows with unique identifiers
identifier_rows = {}

# Read the input CSV file
with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
header = next(reader)  # Read the header

for row in reader:
    if row[0] == '1':
        # Do nothing for rows where column 1 is '1'
        pass
    elif row[0] == '2':
        # Columns 2, 3, and 4 are unique identifiers
        identifier = tuple(row[1:4])
        value = float(row[4])

        if identifier in identifier_rows:
            # Update the sum of column 5 for existing rows
            identifier_rows[identifier] += value
        else:
            # Add the row to the dictionary
            identifier_rows[identifier] = value

# Write the output CSV file
with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as file:
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(header)  # Write the header

# Write the rows with column 1 as '1'
with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip the header

    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == '1':
            writer.writerow(row)

# Write the aggregated rows with column 1 as '2'
for identifier, value in identifier_rows.items():
    writer.writerow(['2'] + list(identifier) + [str(value)])

print("New CSV file output 4 has been created successfully.")
```

And got the below output (Incorrect Output):

[image]

But it needs to be grouped by each header row (i.e., row where column 1 = '1').

Comment: Are you unable to use pandas? It makes such data transformation more seamless

Comment: Please provide sample data (text) to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about the data structure that will hold each group and track the sums.

For the first subset of rows, that looks, to me, like:

```py
{
    ("2", "1010", "2105", "NONE"): -200.0,
    ("2", "1050", "2105", "NONE"): -150.0,
    ("2", "1010", "2105", "COSF"): -150.2,
    ("2", "1010", "2104", "NONE"): -75.0,
    ("2", "1010", "2104", "COSF"): -75.1,
}
```

That's a dict with the first four fields as a tuple as the key to value (the sum).

You'd also need to store the header for this subset:

```py
header = ['1', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

Then you'll need to sort and format the floats, then append those as rows to a list of final rows.

Then, repeat for each subset of rows, delimited by a header which starts with "1".

Everytime you find that header row in the input, you update the final rows with the **last set** of grouped sums, and reset the state variables for the next set:

```py
...
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == "1":
            update_final(header)
            header = row
            grouped_sums = {}
            continue
...
```

Every other row should be data you want to group and sum:

```py
...
        key = tuple(row[:4])
        val = float(row[4])

        sum = grouped_sums.get(key, 0.0)
        sum += val
        grouped_sums[key] = sum
```

You also need to deal with data still in the state/global vars after the last row:

```py
...
    update_final(header)
```

Here's the whole script.  I use type hints, and it really helped me here get all the lists and tuples straight:

```py
import csv

Row = list[str]
Group_Key = tuple[str, str, str, str]
Subset_Row = tuple[str, str, str, str, float]

# global vars to update in the main loop of the input CSV; and read from in update_final()
header: Row = []
grouped_sums: dict[Group_Key, float] = {}
# global var to update in update_final(); and read from to write to output CSV
final_rows: list[Row] = []


def update_final(header: Row):
    # initial call for first row of CSV, nothing collected/grouped/summed yet
    if len(grouped_sums) == 0:
        return

    # create intermediate list of groups to sort
    subet: list[Subset_Row] = []
    for key, sum in grouped_sums.items():
        subet.append(key + (sum,))
    subet.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2], x[4]))

    # add to final
    final_rows.append(header)
    for row in subet:
        final_rows.append(list(row[:4]) + [f"{row[4]:.3f}"])


with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == "1":
            update_final(header)
            # reset state vars
            header = row
            grouped_sums = {}
            # no values to sum, skip to next row
            continue

        key = tuple(row[:4])
        val = float(row[4])

        sum = grouped_sums.get(key, 0.0)
        sum += val
        grouped_sums[key] = sum

    update_final(header)

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerows(final_rows)
```

I got the final output pretty close to what you showed in the image; there's a small sorting discrepancy in the last set:

```
1,AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD
2,1010,2104,COSF,-75.100
2,1010,2104,NONE,-75.000
2,1010,2105,NONE,-200.000
2,1010,2105,COSF,-150.200
2,1050,2105,NONE,-150.000
1,AAB,BBB,ССС,DDD
2,1010,2104,NONE,-75.000
2,1010,2105,NONE,-275.100
2,1050,2105,NONE,-150.000
1,AAC,BBB,CCC,DDD
2,1010,2104,COSF,-75.100
2,1010,2104,NONE,-75.000
2,1010,2105,NONE,-200.000
2,1010,2105,COSF,-150.200
2,1050,2105,NONE,-150.000
```